# How to convert a number in a substring to date format in SQL?

Tags: sql

How do I format this particular example to a dd-mm-yyyy format?

In table say table1, we have a string in the following format where I need to take the date value out.

```
AB-20092018-data1 
CD-21918-notsodata1
EF-31012017-data1
GH-31117-notsodata
```

Comment: Looks like this should really be three separate columns.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: This is in one column.  I have no problems in separating them out.  But when the query tries to extract "31117", I get the "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: This is in SQL server database.

Comment: You have non standard date formats buried in your strings, and even `TRY_CONVERT` does not seem to be able to cope with them, [see the demo here](https://rextester.com/VEZP78687).  So, I recommend fixing your date data before you bring it into SQL Server.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to do the whole conversion in SQL.

Comment: The shorter ones are the issue.  Is 31117 1/31/2017 or 11/3/2017?  More generally, what is the format of the "notsodata" ones?

Comment: I don't see how you can tell if `31117` is `03-11-17` or `31-01-17`

Comment: Yes, the short ones are mind boggling.  Cannot figure this out so far.  The format "DDMYY" as a string is the main concern and unfortunately this cannot be rectified before the data is stored in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As above your `31117` records are going to be quite hard to determine what the actual date is supposed to be.

You can do something very messy like this to get your date format out of the ones that actually have a date in it.

```
SELECT   cast(right(convert1, 4) + '/' + substring(convert1, 3, 2) + '/' + left(convert1, 2) as date) as LongDate1
FROM    (
    select left(substring('EF-31012017-data1',CHARINDEX('-','EF-31012017-data1') +1,len('EF-31012017-data1')),charindex('-',substring('EF-31012017-data1',CHARINDEX('-','EF-31012017-data1') +1,len('EF-31012017-data1')))-1) Convert1
) longer
```

Comment: Thank you all for your input.  Still haven't found a solution though for the "31117" string format conversion to date.

Comment: It is physically impossible to tell what the date is from that string unless you know what the format is. is it 3-11-17 or 31-1-17? you will have to see if you can find another way to get a datetime field into your extract.

Comment: I am now trying to figure out how to insert a "0" in "31117" such as "31012017" (ddmmyyyy) after discarding the rest of the characters.  Then convert this value to date.